# White line between tableView header and refreshControl

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to create a profile with a  color, like Vine. But when I pull to refresh I put the same color and I see a white line, that gets bigger and smalls while you pull. Do you know a way to eliminate or accomplish this?

I want to do profiles like Vine where you have a full color and you can refresh

The color of the header is simple

```
let tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width,259))
tableHeaderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple()
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
```

[image]

Comment: did you manage to make it?

Comment: @JoanCardona I re-do it from scratch and works